# Getting the error 'GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE' undeclared (first use in this function) while working with cocos 2d engine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i was working with the cocos 2d engine which i integrated in the xcode version 3.2.2.I started with the downloaded application which gave the error as 'GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE' undeclared , later i tried with the blank project ,its still giving the same error.
I dont know whats wrong and where. please suggest me how to integrate cocos2d in xcode 3 and what all settings to do

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Cocos2D v1.0 Release Notes](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/release_notes:1_0_0) you'll see that the minimum requirement is Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS 4.1. You said you're using Xcode 3.2.2. There's your problem, probably.

If you still want to use Xcode 3 then you can [get the latest version 3.2.6 here](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792). Personally I recommend to upgrade to Xcode 4.x for the simple reason that you can't create iOS 5 apps with Xcode 3 and Xcode 3 being incompatible with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score 0):

May be the file related to that is missing.

Comment: i downloaded the framework and added it to the xcode and tried to run the blank project , still its giving the error.What file can be missing

Answer (score 0):

That definitely looks like a compile-type error, one generally caused simply by not having that symbol defined at the point where you want to use it.

Any number of things could be going wrong here. Here's a couple of things to check.

- Are you including the correct header file (`glext.h`, I believe) in your sample?
- Is that header file being picked up from the correct location (you may have other similarly named files in other places)?
- Does that (or any other header file) even *have* that symbol defined?
- If they do, do you have the correct defines so that you can see them (ofthen `#define` statements are themselves inside `#ifdef` ones)?

Comment: i am getting the error in cocos 2d framework files..The same files are working fine in xcode version 4

Comment: @sujay, I don't have any _specific_ knowledge of what you're trying to do - all I can do is interpret the error and offer general advice on how to track down the problem.

Comment: it would be helpful if you suggest me some steps to install and run a cocos 2d engine on xcode 3 ..

Comment: @sujay, then you'll have to wait for another answer from someone more au fait with your specific environment, I'm afraid. In the meantime, it would do you a world of good to follow up each of those points above - you'll get far better at developing code if you learn how to do it yourself rather than being hand-held. Not trying to insult you or anything but developers become good at what they do by getting their hands dirty :-)